# compiling in bluej?

Tags: java

```
class box {
  double ht,wdt,len;

  box(double h,double w,double l) {
    ht=h;
    wdt=w;
    len=l;
  }

  double volume() {
    return ht*wdt*len;
  }
}


class boxme {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    box mybox= new box(1,2,3);
    System.out.print("The volume is "+mybox.volume());
  }
}
```

// For this code to be run in bluej,i still need to give the arguments after the object creation (though I have already given them in my code).The same code works well in cmd but shows this difference when attempted in bluej.Please provide a reason and solution to bring out an equivalence between bluej and cmd?? //

Comment: I would strongly recommend Capitalizing the first letter of class names. Unfortunately I haven't used blueJ for a while.. I'm not a massive fan!

Answer (score 1):

When you have two different classes and you want to use the methods in the other class, you have to create an instance of that class.

Right-click on the second class and run the `public static void main(String args[])` function.

And please note the name of the class must start with an upper case letter and the fields must be `private` scoped for security, Objects should be always in lower case.

```
public class Box {   
  private double ht,wdt,len;

  public Box(double h,double w,double l) {
    ht=h;
    wdt=w;
    len=l;
  }

  public double volume() {
    return ht*wdt*len;
  }
}
public class boxme {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Box mybox= new Box(1,2,3);
    System.out.print("The volume is "+mybox.volume());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an object while running it in BlueJ explicitly, since you already have the main function defined.

Right click on the class and run the public static void main(String args[])
 function.

Comment: why is bluej not taking the predefined arguments passed??

Comment: How are you running it ? Show me a screenshot? Upload it here http://imagebin.org/index.php?page=add